# Как выполнить сортировку в Prisma для поля с числами

Tags: postgresql, typescript, prisma

Есть вот такой код:

```
if (category && city) {
        return this.prisma.task.findMany({
          where: {
            AND: [
              {category: category},
              {address: {contains: city}}
            ]
          },
          orderBy: [
            {commentsCount: sortDirection},
          ],
          take: limit,
          skip: page > 0 ? limit * (page - 1) : undefined,
        });
      }
```

Хочу выполнить сортировку(orderBy) по полю `commentsCount` в котором храниться количество комментариев и получаю ошибку:

```
Type '{ commentsCount: "desc" | "asc"; }' is not assignable to type 'TaskOrderByWithRelationInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'commentsCount' does not exist in type 'TaskOrderByWithRelationInput'.ts(2322)
```

Искал в доках и на разных ресурсах как выполняется сортировка и везде один и тот же затасканный пример с сортировкой по дате создания (createdAt). А как делается сортировка для поля с числом я так нигде и не нашёл.
Может тут кто подскажет, почему сортировка не работает.

Comment: у вас ошибка не призмы, а тайпскрипта `'commentsCount' does not exist in type 'TaskOrderByWithRelationInput'` до выполнения запроса дело не дошло

Comment: @nörbörnën даже если всё дело в тайпскрипте, легче от этого не становится. Как её отловить я даже не представляю.

Comment: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value

Answer (score 0):

Похоже нет в Призме встроенного метода для сортировки по числам.
По крайней мере я не нашёл и здесь никто не ответил.

Поэтому убрал orderBy из кода и получил не отсортированный массив тасков.
А затем уже с помощью Array.prototype.sort вручную отсортировал полученный массив:
`return tasks.sort((taskA, taskB) => taskB.commentsCount - taskA.commentsCount);`